# how to match the system date time format with the sql parameters datetime type in java

Tags: java, sql, datetime

When I run my jsp page:

```
 Exception in Display Bean in getDbTable(String code):
     com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type
     varchar to datetime
```

is displayed. I have a stored procedure which has parameters of datetime type. To make it dynamic I stored the system date and time in a variable and passed it as the argument of stored procedure sql command:

```
clstmt = con.prepareCall("exec vcs_gauge 'vs1_bag','d','currentDate'") ;
```

Comment: MY sql commad is clstmt = con.prepareCall("exec vcs_gauge 'vs1_bag','d','currentDate'") ; where d and currenttime is Date d = new Date();
    Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3600 * 1000);

Comment: When you try to map a date which is `varchar` in database to `java.util.Date`, you will get exceptions.

Comment: as stated by the error message, `'currentDate'` is not a date it's a string

Comment: @DarshanLila in database these arguments are of datetime only

Comment: @MeghaSharma Exception states otherwise. May be you are sending a date parameter which is string. Basically a cast issue, examine code carefully you should be able to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like:

```
clstmt = con.prepareCall("exec vcs_gauge 'vs1_bag', 'd', :date");
clstmt.setDate("date", new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime())); // assumes currentDate is a j.u.Date
```

see [`CallableStatement#setDate(java.lang.String,java.sql.Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setDate(java.lang.String,%20java.sql.Date))

Comment: Exception in Display Bean in getDbTable(String code):java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date occurs when I do     clstmt = con.prepareCall("exec vcs_gauge 'vs1_bag', 'd', :date");
 clstmt.setDate("date", (java.sql.Date) currentDate);.Please help me out.

Comment: thanx.but still error Exception in Display Bean in getDbTable(String code):java.lang.NullPointerException is shown.

Comment: Date d = new Date();
 Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3600 * 1000);
   
clstmt.setDate("date", new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime())); 
 clstmt = con.prepareCall("exec vcs_gauge 'vs1_bag', 'd', 'date'")
             
This is my code.Earlier when i passed parameters as clstmt = con.prepareCall("exec vcs_gauge @gauge_name='vs1_bag',@first_rec_time='2014-09-01 10:00:00',@last_rec_time='2014-09-01 11:00:00'") ;Then data was retrieved from database.